# JDBC retrieve foreign keys columns name (sybase ase)

Tags: jdbc, foreign-keys, sap-ase

I'm trying to retrieve FK of a given table with JDBC metadata.
For that, I'm using the "getImportedKeys" function.

For my table 'cash_mgt_strategy', it give in resultset:

```
PKTABLE_CAT : 'HAWK'
PKTABLE_SCHEM : 'dbo'
PKTABLE_NAME : 'fx_execution_strategy_policy'
PKCOLUMN_NAME : 'fx_execution_strategy_policy_id'
FKTABLE_CAT  : 'HAWK'
FKTABLE_SCHEM  : 'dbo'
FKTABLE_NAME  : 'cash_mgt_strategy'
FKCOLUMN_NAME  : 'fx_est_execution_strategy_policy'
KEY_SEQ  : '1'
UPDATE_RULE  : '1'
DELETE_RULE  : '1'
FK_NAME  : 'fk_fx_est_execution_strategy_policy'
PK_NAME  : 'cash_mgt_s_1283127861'
DEFERRABILITY  : '7'
```

The problem is that the "FKCOLUMN_NAME  : 'fx_est_execution_strategy_policy'" is not a real column of my table, but it seems to be truncated? (missing "_id" at the end)

When using an official Sybase sql client (Sybase Workspace), displaying the DDL of the table give for this constraint / foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.cash_mgt_strategy ADD CONSTRAINT fk_fx_est_execution_strategy_policy FOREIGN KEY (fx_est_execution_strategy_policy_id)
REFERENCES HAWK.dbo.fx_execution_strategy_policy (fx_execution_strategy_policy_id)
```

So I'm wondering how to retrieve the full FKCOLUMN_NAME ?

Note that I'm using jconnect 6.0.
I've tested with jconnect 7.0, same problem.

Thanks

Comment: Note that I've tested the symetric way, by using "getExportedKeys" on the PK table... but it give exactly the same result / problem.

Comment: Ok, so I've checked the getMaxColumnNameLength(); which is 30. But what is really strange is that, when I retrieve the columns of my table with "getColumns()" function, I've succesfully retrieve the whole name 'fx_est_execution_strategy_policy_id'. And here the name retrieved is 'fx_est_execution_strategy_policy', which is 33 char lenght, not 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided your ASE version so I'm going to assume the following:

- dataserver was running ASE 12.x at some point (descriptor names limited to 30 characters)
- dataserver was upgraded to ASE 15.x/16.x (descriptor names extended to 255 characters)
- DBA failed to upgrade/update the sp_jdbc* procs after the upgrade to ASE 15.x/16.x (hence the old ASE 12.x version of the procs - descriptors limited to 30 characters - are still in use in the dataserver)

If the above is true then `sp_version` should show the older versions of the jdbc procs running in the dataserver.

The (obvious) solution would be to have the DBA load the latest version of the jdbc stored procs (typically found under ${SYBASE}/jConnect*/sp).

NOTE: Probably wouldn't hurt to have the DBA review the output from `sp_version` to see if there are any other upgrade scripts that need to be loaded (eg, `installmodel`, `installsecurity`, `installcommit`, etc).

Comment: You're right about migration from 12 to 16. sp_version result contains 9 lines, 8 lines refer to 16.0 SP2; 1 refer to jconnect for jdbc 1004. The 9 lines are in status "complete". I've written to DBA to check this bug and patch jdbc stored proc. Hope I will have the patch in few months... :/  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It looks like I misspoke ... looking at the stored procs that come with ASE 16.0 SP02 PL04 ... the `keys` column in the `#jfkeys`/`#jpkeys` tables are still coded as `varchar(32)`; unless the ASE 16.0 SP03 codeline has been fixed, you'll need to open a case with tech support to get this permanently fixed; in the meantime a quick edit of the proc and/or install script (change the `keys` columns to `varchar(257)`)  should get you over this hump ... though you'll want to keep your eye out for any other discrepancies

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've done some search on my DB server and I've found the code of stored proc sp_jdbc_importkey. In this code can see:

```
create table #jfkey_res( 
    PKTABLE_CAT        varchar(32) null,
    PKTABLE_SCHEM      varchar(32) null,
    PKTABLE_NAME       varchar(257) null,
    PKCOLUMN_NAME      varchar(257) null,
    FKTABLE_CAT        varchar(32) null,
    FKTABLE_SCHEM      varchar(32) null,
    FKTABLE_NAME       varchar(257) null,
    FKCOLUMN_NAME      varchar(257) null,
    KEY_SEQ            smallint,
    UPDATE_RULE        smallint,
    DELETE_RULE        smallint,
    FK_NAME            varchar(257),
    PK_NAME            varchar(257) null)
create table #jpkeys(seq int, keys varchar(32) null)
create table #jfkeys(seq int, keys varchar(32) null)
```

The temporary tables #jpkeys and #jfkeys used to store the column names (for PK and FK) are typed with varchar(32) instead of 257!!

Need to search how to patch / update theses stored proc now.